# sort row data by leaving 1st row ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How we can avoid the sorting 1st row of the ag-grid?
the example I have 10 rows in the grid I want only 9 rows to sorted by leaving the 1st of the ag-grid?
I have tried all the possible code and googled some examples but no luck

```
<ag-grid-angular style="height: 453px;"
                   class="ag-theme-bootstrap"
                   border-color="#FFFFF"
                   [enableSorting]="true"
                   [rowData]="serviceLineSurveyMaplist"
                   [pinnedTopRowData]="templateSurveyMapList"
                   [columnDefs]="mappedSurveyColumns"
                   [enableFilter]="true"
                   (gridReady)="onMapSurveyGridReady($event)"
                   [getRowStyle]="getrowstyles"
                   rowSelection="multiple">

  </ag-grid-angular>
in ts file
     this.serviceLineSurveyMaplist = result;
          for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            debugger;
            this.templateSurveyMapList.push(this.serviceLineSurveyMaplist[i]);
          }
```

I have some rows in  serviceLineSurveyMaplist I want to pin

Comment: Is there a chance to mark that first row as a header row? I'm not an ag-grid guru (: just want to share an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Row pinning feature](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/)

Have a look at this live example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/#example-row-pinning. Try sorting on any column.

In your case, just pin the first row using `this.gridApi.setPinnedTopRowData(rows)`.

As per [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/#non-supported-items), pinned row doesn't support sorting, which fulfills your requirement.

Comment: i have used setPinnedTopRowData has u said but not working out